# How to convert sgn() function in ms-access to t-sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, ms-access

How to convert `sgn()` function in Access to T-SQL in the following query:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT Customer.Branch_ID, 
    Customer.Bankrupt, 
    -Sgn([Bankrupt]) AS [Counts]
FROM 
    Customer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [`SIGN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188420.aspx) in TSQL:

> Returns the positive (+1), zero (0), or negative (-1) sign of the
>   specified expression.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customer.Branch_ID, 
    Customer.Bankrupt, -SIGN([Bankrupt]) AS [Counts] 
FROM Customer
```